# Does Starship perform a launch tower avoidance maneuver?

Tags: launch, spacex-starship, rcs, stability, avoidance

Does Starship perform a launch tower avoidance maneuver? If yes, is this accomplished using gimbaled raptor engines or RCS rockets? How far laterally is the Starship axis shifted by this maneuver and how are related stresses managed?

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190033307/downloads/20190033307.pdf describes “an initial small tower avoidance maneuver” of Saturn V. It also states

> Problems in vehicle control arise because Saturn vehicles cannot be
> considered rigid but must be treated as distributed masses connected
> by an elastic structure. Forces acting on these masses resulting from
> atmospheric perturbations or active control of the vehicle excite the
> complex spring-mass system and cause body bending. Since the structure
> possesses low damping, oscillatory bending modes of considerable
> amplitude can be produced; the control sensors may be subjected to
> these large amplitude oscillations at their particular location. Thus
> incorrect information about the total vehicle behavior may cause
> self-excitation and instability of the vehicle control system.

This description makes it sound like the Texas Two-Step required to yaw, then straighten, the rocket’s course in the first seconds of launch could produce significant bending moments in the stack.